# A manga with A weak guy that meets his future strong self and he uses his future self's memory and power to kill the demon kings

Tags: story-identification, comics, manga, demons, reincarnation

I totally don't remember the title, but, I clearly remember the plot.

It starts with the guy and a little girl, the girl is the strongest knight and the guy is the weakest person in their village. The guy is the little girl caretaker, he helps her with shower, clothes, and many other things.

In the middle of the chapter, the guy was feeling skeptical cause he can do anything for her, but, he can't protect her. So, he kept training without her knowing, when he was training, he met his future self.

His future self told him that a demon king/lord is going to come to their village and the girl is going to get killed by that demon.

He was furious, his future self, knowing full well what the guy is feeling gave his power and memory to the guy.
A few days later, the demon lord/king really did come to their village. The guy haven't realised he got his future self's power so he was just stuck with the memory of the girl dying it repeated in his head since his future self said it.

He was worried about the girl cause if she fights with the demon lord she'll die, but she's the strongest knight in their village, so she can't just ignore the demon lord/king destroying the village, but in the middle of their fight, the Image of the girl dying suddenly popped up in his head, without any second thoughts, he runs to the girl and tries to save her.

Right at that moment, his power from the future shows up and he's able to save the girl.
A lot more things happened after that but I can't describe it very well

Answer (score 2):

It's [Ragna crimson](https://mangadex.org/title/21599/ragna-crimson) by Kobayashi Daiki.

I can't believe I missed the title as I was scrolling through my history.

> Ragna is a dragon hunter along with his partner, the strongest dragon hunter Leo. He didn't have much talent at hunting dragons but he had decided to entrust his whole life for her. However he was shown the feel of true despair by his future self on what would happen if he stays weak as he is now. With that, it seems that the reaper of the dragons had now appeared earlier than the original history, but will it be enough to change the future?

Comment: You can accept an answer (even your own) by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].